# Need examples to communicate with a KEITHLEY 4200 via RS232

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, pyvisa

I've been trying to communicate using RS232 and PyVisa with a Keithley 4200. I made all the installation of all the modules I suppose to need. But it keeps sending errors like "timeout to respond", can't recognize commands like the "*IND?" command (also tried the '\n\r'), etc. And according to the guide, the commans for GPIB are the same for RS232.

Honestly I'm new with Python, I would appreciate a little help sharing information to make it work (examples, tips, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

```
import visa
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
print (rm.list_resources())  #List the resources visible to pyVISA
inst = rm.open_resource("ASRL38::INSTR")  #Enter Serial port here
print (inst.timeout)
inst.timeout = 4000  #increased timeout from default of 2000
print(inst.query("*IDN?"))  #basic instrument name query
```

Check the baud rate on the instrument.  I had to set it to 9600.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot involved here and the problem is probably not because of python.

I'm not familiar with the Keithley 4200, however, looking through the manual, if you want to control it from an external PC then you'll need to set up the KXCI (Keithley External Control Interface). I believe it can only be done via GPIB or ethernet. RS-232 can only be used to control other equipment from the 4200 (like a probe).